# Google Analytics not working on AWS hosted website

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-analytics

so I have my website hosted in AWS ( treeapp.co ). 
I'm trying to connect my Google Analytics (GA). So I created an acc. and GA told me to input the below code in the header of my website.

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXXX-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-1');
</script>
```

I've obviously taken out my ref number and replaced by XXXXXXXXX.

However I still can't receive any data. **Any thoughts on why?** ( and I know people have been on the website)

Comment: GA can take a bit of time for data to show up.  How long has this been enabled?

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer.
It's been approximately 45mins. You think I should still wait longer?

Comment: OK its working now! It would a weird huge amount of time but works! thanks!